# jQuery - Usando evento click em div pai e filho

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho duas div. Estou tentando fazer o seguinte. Quando eu clicar na div pai ele deve retornar o alert. Mas quando eu clicar na div filho nada deve acontecer. Tentei algo abaixo, mas não tive sucesso.

Eu sei que não funcionou porque ele está chamando dois eventos, o da div pai, e o da div filho. Mas não sei como impedir que ele não chame o evento da div pai ao clicar na div filho.

Exeste alguma forma simples de fazer isso com jQuery?

```js
$('.pai, .filho').click(function(){
  
   if($(this).attr('class') == 'pai') { 
     alert('teste');
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="pai">
  Pai
  <div class="filho">Filho</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se bem percebi quer que o evento não propague para o filho mas que dispare ao clicar no pai (clicar em qualquer sitio do pai excepto no filho). Tem de dar um `e.stopPropagation();` ao filho também no evento `click`:

```js
$(".pai").on('click', function(){
    alert('teste');
});
$(".filho").on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log('não vou fazer nada');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="pai">
  Pai
  <div class="filho">Filho</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Opa! era exatamente isso que eu estava procurando. Valeu! ;)

Comment: Ainda bem que  resolveu @alan. De nada